# Install rpm after copy, with ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, devops

I have an ansible playbook which will copy a file into a location on a remote server. It works fine. In this case, the file is an rpm. This is the way it works:

```
---
- hosts: my_host
  tasks:
    - name: mkdir /tmp/RPMS
      file: path=/tmp/RPMS state=directory

    - name: copy RPMs to /tmp/RPMS
      copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: /tmp/RPMS
        mode: 0755
      with_items:
        [any_rpm-x86_64.rpm]
      register: rpms_copied
```

Now, with the file successfully on the remote server, I need to start some new logic that will install the rpm that sits in /tmp/RPMS. I have run many different versions of the below (So this code is added onto the above block):

```
    - name: install rpm from file
  yum:
    name: /tmp/RPMS/any_rpm-x86_64.rpm
    state: present
  become: true
```

I don't know if the formatting is incorrect, or if this is not the way. Can anyone advise as to how I can get the rpm in the directory /tmp/RPMS installed using a new few lines in the existing playbook?

Thanks.

Comment: I have two down-votes without any comments on this, can someone tell me what their problem is and I can act to rectify

Comment: What is the error you're getting ? Note1: the yaml of the task you pasted is invalid but I guess it is a copy/paste error... Note2: installing through shell as you proposed in your self solution below is discouraged. It is not idempotent. Using the yum or package module is the way to go and should work as proposed provided your format your task yaml correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I did not find this anywhere else, and it genuinely took me all of my working day to get to this point. For anyone else struggling:

```
- name: Install my package from a file on server
  shell: rpm -ivh /tmp/RPMS/*.rpm
  async: 1800
  poll: 0
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```